# Why can a partial class only contain partial classes?

Tags: c#, partial-classes

I struggle to understand, why a class with the `partial` modifier, can not contain classes that are not `partial`. They don't need to necessarily have their definition spread across multiple files.

Conversely, to me it makes more sense to require classes containing a partial class, to also be partial. But this is not the case, even though a class can't have definition in another class, without its parent class also being defined there.

Am I just not understanding partial correctly?

Comment: _"why a class with the `partial` modifier, can not contain classes that are not `partial`"_ [it can!](https://rextester.com/ZJAZ16054)

Comment: So, if a class is partial, and in contains a fully defined class, can I use that class in the other file?

Comment: Yes, see the link above. If you're having a _specific_ problem, please [edit] the question and include the code that demonstrates that problem.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not currently near a computer, so editing would be hard, but that actually clears it up for me.